# VB Script to seperate text into multiple files

Tags: text, vbscript, extract

I am trying to create a VBscript file that will seperate a text file into multiple text files. I haven't done any programming in a while and I have been banging my head with this for a few days.

This is part of the text file.

```
Tested on,8 May 2016,,,,
Asset ID,126567,,,,
Rigel 288,Z48-0366,,,,
Site,Workshop,,,,
Location,WORKSHOP,,,,
AP Setup,,0,,,
User Name,Workshop,,,,
Test Sequence,TestCode-BGC2,,,,
Live Voltage,,, 248,,,V
Neutral Voltage,,, 2,,,V
Load Current,,, 0.0,,,A
Load Test,,, 0.0,,,kVA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Normal,, 8,Pass,100,µA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Normal,SFC: Neutral Open, 12,Pass,500,µA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Reversed,, 8,Pass,100,µA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Reversed,SFC: Neutral Open, 12,Pass,500,µA
User Comment,,,,
Status,Pass

Tested on,8 May 2016,,,,
Asset ID,126563,,,,
Rigel 288,Z48-0366,,,,
Site,Workshop,,,,
Location,WORKSHOP,,,,
AP Setup,,0,,,
User Name,Workshop,,,,
Test Sequence,TestCode-BGC2,,,,
Live Voltage,,, 247,,,V
Neutral Voltage,,, 2,,,V
Load Current,,, 0.0,,,A
Load Test,,, 0.0,,,kVA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Normal,, 8,Pass,100,µA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Normal,SFC: Neutral Open, 12,Pass,500,µA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Reversed,, 8,Pass,100,µA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Reversed,SFC: Neutral Open, 13,Pass,500,µA
User Comment,,,,
Status,Pass

Tested on,8 May 2016,,,,
Asset ID,126555,,,,
Rigel 288,Z48-0366,,,,
Site,Workshop,,,,
Location,WORKSHOP,,,,
AP Setup,,0,,,
User Name,Workshop,,,,
Test Sequence,TestCode-BGC2,,,,
Live Voltage,,, 245,,,V
Neutral Voltage,,, 2,,,V
Load Current,,, 0.0,,,A
Load Test,,, 0.0,,,kVA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Normal,, 8,Pass,100,µA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Normal,SFC: Neutral Open, 12,Pass,500,µA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Reversed,, 8,Pass,100,µA
Enclosure Lkg,Mains Reversed,SFC: Neutral Open, 12,Pass,500,µA
User Comment,,,,
Status,Pass
```

I need to be able to seperate each bit from start of string "Tested" and end of the string "Status,Pass" into seperate text files which need to be named after the specific asset ID e.g, "126567.txt"
If this could repeat until the end of file as there will be more than 3, usually around 40.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code you've *"been banging my head with for a few days"*? So far apart from a file structure you've shown us nothing.

Comment: What have you accomplished with your head-banging? What problems have you encountered? Is the source file small enough that it can be read into a single string? This sounds like a job for regular expressions -- have you looked into how they work with VBScript?

Answer (score 1):

Give the below a try.  I wrote it in VBA so let me know if you run into any issues.  I think using Regular Expressions would be the quickest and easiest method to parse and pull out the values that you need.  Let me know if you have any questions.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Dim objFSO, objFile, objRegEx
Dim objRegRes, strMatch, strID, strLine
Dim strFilePath, strOutFolder, strRead

'Path to your Main File
strFilePath = "C:\Path\ToFile\test.txt"

'Declare the File Scripting Object To Open, Create, and Read Text Files
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Check if File Exists
If Not objFSO.FileExists(strFilePath) Then
    MsgBox "Cannot Find The File"
    WScript.Quit
End If

'Create Regular Expression object to parse the file
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.MultiLine = True
'Capture all lines that starts with 'Tested' and ends with 'Status,Pass' _
'with a SubMatch or Capture Group for the Value between 'Asset ID,' and the next ','
objRegEx.Pattern = "^Tested on[\s\S]*?Asset ID\,(\S*?)\,[\s\S]*?Status\,Pass$"

'Save the Folder Path of the Main File to a Seperate Variable
strOutFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(strFilePath) & Chr(92)

'Open and Read the Main File into a Variable
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath, ForReading, False)
strRead = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
Set objFile = Nothing

'Execute the Regular Expression and Loop through the results
Set objRegRes = objRegEx.Execute(strRead)
For Each strMatch In objRegRes
    strLine = Trim(strMatch)
    strID = Trim(strMatch.SubMatches(0))
    'Create Individual Text Files For Each Match - *Will OverWrite Files If They Exist
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strOutFolder & strID & ".txt", True)
    objFile.Write strLine    'Change to: 'objFile.WriteLine' if you want an ending Carriage Return
    objFile.Close

    'Optional Cleanup
    Set objFile = Nothing
    strLine = vbNullString
    strID = vbNullString
Next

MsgBox "Completed"
WScript.Quit
```

I copied the text of your post for my test and it appeared to work for me...